# Finding the least squares solution of a vector when it is added to another vector in a larger system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, pseudoinverse

Suppose I have the following system relating force to flux in a magnetic actuator
\begin{align}
\vec{F} &= \mathbb{C}\vec{\Phi^2}\\
\vec{F} &=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_x\\
F_y
\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbb{C} &= c
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\vec{\Phi^2}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_w^2\\
\Phi_n^2\\
\Phi_e^2\\
\Phi_s^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The forces are known as is the constant $c$ in the $\mathbb{C}$ matrix. If I use the Moore-Penrose inverse to solve for $\vec{\Phi^2}$, I will obtain a solution that minimizes it's L2-norm (least-squares fit solution). But suppose each flux term is a summation of a bias flux term and a coil flux term (i.e. $\Phi_w = \Phi_{wb}+\Phi_{wc}$) and I want to minimize the norm of the vector of coil fluxes:
\begin{align}
\vec{\Phi_c} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{wc}\\
\Phi_{nc}\\
\Phi_{ec}\\
\Phi_{sc}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Each term in $\vec{\Phi^2}$ has the structure $\Phi^2 = (\Phi_c^2+2\Phi_c\Phi_b+\Phi_b^2)$. How do I go about finding the solution that minimizes the L2-norm of $\vec{\Phi_c}$ (i.e. minimize $\Sigma\Phi_{ic}^2$)? Is there a name for this kind of optimization so I can research it further?

Clarification of different vector definitions:
\begin{align}
\vec{\Phi} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{w}\\
\Phi_{n}\\
\Phi_{e}\\
\Phi_{s}\\
\end{bmatrix}
= \vec{\Phi_c}+\vec{\Phi_b} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{wc}+\Phi_{wb}\\
\Phi_{nc}+\Phi_{nb}\\
\Phi_{ec}+\Phi_{eb}\\
\Phi_{sc}+\Phi_{sb}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\vec{\Phi^2} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_w^2\\
\Phi_n^2\\
\Phi_e^2\\
\Phi_s^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{wc}^2+2\Phi_{wc}\Phi_{wb}+\Phi_{wb}^2\\
\Phi_{nc}^2+2\Phi_{nc}\Phi_{nb}+\Phi_{nb}^2\\
\Phi_{ec}^2+2\Phi_{ec}\Phi_{eb}+\Phi_{eb}^2\\
\Phi_{sc}^2+2\Phi_{sc}\Phi_{sb}+\Phi_{sb}^2\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}